# How can I update all models in a collection - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am setting the `value` attribute of all models in a collection (in an `_.each` loop).  After the loop is finished, each `value` attribute is unchanged.  I believe this is because the `_.each` loop is creating a new instance variable for each model.  Is there a standard way to update models of a collection that I am not following?

The code which should force the dice into a straight (1,2,3,4,5,6). `rollableDice` refers to a Backbone collection of Backbone models which have a `value` attribute.  This is a method on a container model:

```js
makeStraight: function() {
  console.log('making straight');
  console.log(_(this.rollableDice.models).pluck('value'));
  var counter = 1;
  _(this.rollableDice.models).each(function(die) {
    console.log(die.get('value'));
    die.set('value', counter);
    console.log(die.get('value'));
    counter++;
  }); 
  console.log(_(this.rollableDice.models).pluck('value'));
},
```

This is the output that I see on the console:

```js
making straight
[1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1]
undefined
1   
undefined
2   
undefined
3   
undefined
4   
undefined
5   
undefined
6   
[1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1]
```

//EDIT
This is the console output that I expect to see:

```js
making straight
[1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1]
1
1   
1
2   
3
3   
5
4   
2
5   
1
6   
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

//EDIT I'm going to show the model code in response to @numbers1311407's response.  I should not be using a model method to store and access attributes.  Instead, I should use the get/set methods or defaults method (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) even while inside the model.  **This is what not to do**:

```
var Die = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'roll')
  },

  value: 1,

  roll: function() {
    this.value = _.random(1,6);
  },
});
```

Comment: Wait, are you using the above model code with the above `makeStraight` method? I ask because `Die.value` is not the same as `Die.attributes.value`. The latter is what gets changed when you call `die.set('value',1)`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing.  @numbers1311407's response below made that clear.  Now I'm using model attributes appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already updating all the models in the collection, but you're deceived into thinking you aren't by accessing the value incorrectly when logging.

```
console.log(_(this.rollableDice.models).pluck('value'));
```

This line does not `get` the value of the model, it's logging a `value` property on the model instance itself, suggesting that you initialized the models improperly.

`pluck` is a collection method (as is `each`, as @SimonBoudrias points out).  You should use the designated methods when working with collections where possible, rather than wrapping them with underscore yourself.

Using `Collection#pluck`, your first and last console logs would look like this:

```
console.log(this.rollableDice.pluck("value"));
```

Using that, you'll see something closer to what you expect, but as pointed out, the initial log will still be an array of `undefined`, as `value` appears to be a property of the model instance, not a proper Model attribute.

Comment: Just for reference, the full lists of Underscore methods mixed into [collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) and [models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods) are in the Backbone docs.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the `collection.each` method.

```
myCollection.each(function(model) {
 // do stuff
});
```

Checkout Underscore.js method extend by Backbone.Collection: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods